# skype web sdk audio service pluginnotfound error

Tags: ionic-framework, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am running demo code of Skype web sdk for the audio service in my IONIC App.

```
var conversation = application.conversationsManager.getConversation('tel:+XXXX');
conversation.selfParticipant.audio.state.when('Connected', function () {
    console.log('Connected to audio call');
});
conversation.state.changed(function (newValue, reason, oldValue) {
    console.log('Conversation state changed from', oldValue, 'to', newValue);
});
conversation.participants.added(function (participant) {
    console.log('Participant:', participant.displayName(), 'has been added to the conversation');
});
conversation.audioService.start().then(function() {
    console.log('The call has been started successfully');
}, function (error) {
    console.log('An error occured starting the call', error);
});
```

When I run this code, I am getting error, Plugin not found. There's no description about what plugin they want.